# PHP/MYSQL to create similar posts type script (similar images)

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am a beginner at using mysql/phpmyadmin, and have never used a cms before. I'm trying to get my head around how I could possibly add a 'similar posts' type script - but instead of showing posts, I would like to show some similar images (similar projects) when viewing each project page of my website.

My website setup is fairly simple:

1. main html page
2. profile html page
3. portfolio php page -> has thumbnail images with links to php generated url project pages
4. project page -> a dynamic php page that generates pages from pagination
5. contact html page.

The project php page has a jquery slideshow, project title and project overview text. The page uses three sql database tables for the data (slideshow images/text, page id for the pagination and one for normalisation), and uses pagination to change the data, creating a page for each project.

I'd really appreciate any ideas/opinions on how I could go about doing this - with sql, or  am better off using a CMS (if so, do you know of a really simple one that could suit my website setup?).

Comment: Try WordPress http://wordpress.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're mainly wondering how you determine similarity, then you can do that with a [text search in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). I also found this page if you want to go to the trouble of building a [tagging database schema](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/TagSchema). The former is simpler, but the latter is a really useful if you want to practice joins.